# how to update system application with a JNI library?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, apk

We have a custom Launcher application that is compiled as part of the AOSP. This launcher also requires a JNI library to function.

Example:

- /system/app/mylauncher.apk
- /system/lib/libmylauncher.so

If this was a "normal" Eclipse application with a library, the exported APK would contain both  the application and the library. However since this is generated from a system image build, the .so is copied into the file system, the APK does not contain the library.

How do you create a system application update APK which includes the library? (and is signed properly to run as a system application)

AFAIK, this can not be done with Eclipse since one of the imported packages is not known by the SDK.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your Android.mk.